# Vim tips community

Tags: discussion

I was watching my colleague use vim, and I gave them some tips to do something more efficiently and they thanked me a lot.

I learned it from the manual, but I realized that it would be nice to have someone look at me use vim even for 5 minutes and then get some tips.

Does anyone know if there is a place designed for this? If not would you like to start one?

(I realize this is a different kind of question, so if it doesn't belong here let me know)

Comment: https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki

Comment: A little of topic, but I once wrote a [vim plugin](https://github.com/lucc/vim-tip) that opens a random help topic for you. A bit like the popup notification with a "tip of the day" some applications give you.

Comment: @Heptite want to flesh that out into an answer?

Comment: [This](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1316/10604) and its linked duplicate have a lot of information on tips for this site

Answer (score 4):

The official Vim site at https://www.vim.org/ used to have a tips section, but after discussion on the Vim Users' and Developers' list it was moved to https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki (back when the site was Wikia).