# Are there any FAQs for the main site containing links to useful Vim resources?

Tags: discussion, support

<s>I didn't want to ask a question but to look for a FAQ thread. However, for some reasons I can't search the Meta site (maybe because it's Beta?).</s>  Ok, it looks like the `search` widget has just changed position on all of SE.

Anyway, I searched and I couldn't find an answer: do you have any FAQ thread, containing pointers to useful Vi/Vim resources?

PS amazing idea, to create a SE site for Vim! Can't believe this is in Beta...it's actually one of the first sites I would expect to find on a hierarchy of sites which was born out of a Q&A programming site. I guess most Vim-related questions are currently being asked on the Unix or Ubuntu SE.

Comment: Useful vim *resources* or useful vim *information/tips*?

Comment: @DJMcMayhem I'm not sure, what's the difference? :-) My goal is to learn to use Vim, not to memorize the whole docs. Thus, a tutorial would be a useful resource, as long as it's more advanced  than [this](https://www.openvim.com/). Vice versa, a not-so-useful resource (at least, not so useful for my goal) is [this](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/). Tips & tricks may also be useful, as long as they can help me use Vim better.

Comment: Very similar, probably duplicate: [How do we share general Vim experience? Or can we?](https://vi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1278/51)

Comment: @MartinTournoji slightly different because I ask about existing resources, questions about whom I think would be off-topic on the main site. I self-answered this question with a suggestion, see what you think of it.

Answer (score 1):

I think questions about external learning resources are off-topic because they're too broad, but I'll check the help pages to verify this point. If I'm right, then my suggestion is to have a question with multiple answers here on Meta, following the exact same schema, and for the same reasons, of the questions about statistical programming languages resources on CrossValidated Meta. See an example:

https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/793/internet-support-for-statistics-software

The other solution would be to create a `faq` tag with extensive tag wiki descriptions, in which the learning resources are buried: see the SO tag wiki

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b-faq/info

Finally, a common "fix" to too broad questions on CrossValidated is to make them `Community wiki`. Once a question has been flagged `Community wiki`, users don't gain reputation for answering it, but in exchange for that, broad scope questions such as "which are the best learning resources or tutorials for Vim" become answerable, and they're also easy to search. See here

https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290/what-is-community-wiki

I propose we adopt one of these "surrogate FAQ" systems for the purpose of storing information about learning resources for Vim.

**EDIT**: I checked and yes, I'm convinced that asking the question "can you point me to useful Vim learning resources" on the main site would be against the rules:

https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

as "subjective" and/or "too broad" (but please feel free to correct me, if you believe I'm mistaken). As such, I'm even more convinced that we should use one of the methods I presented above to have a surrogate FAQ system. It works nicely on the SE sites I participate to more actively. One may be concerned about the lack of updates, but I'm convinced that's not a real issue:

- if the "Community Wiki" way is chosen, then the system automatically bumps "Community Wiki" questions to the top of the question list, to attract update efforts
- in the other two cases, there's no real update process in place, other than voluntary contributions by users with the necessary privileges. However, since the list of resources would not be stored on the main site, I don't think we should worry about a possible lack of updates (no one is worried that stuff posted on the chat is updated, or even correct). And anyway, at least the system used by CrossValidated does get regular updates (apparently, high reputation users crave for an opportunity to add more wonderful R links: I cannot disagree with that :-D)